# How can I quickly find the relatively positioned HTML parent element of an absolutely positioned child?

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, google-chrome-devtools

I am working with the following code:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        ...
                            <div class="absolute">Lorem ispum</div>
                        ...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Using Chrome's DevTools, I'd like to be able to quickly find which parent `<div>` element has `position: relative`, so I can know which parent element is determining the origin point of my absolutely positioned element. I can manually inspect each of the divs to find the first parent that is set to `relative` but I'm working with a deeply nested tree, so I'm wondering if there is a faster way to find the parent I'm trying to find. A Javascript snippet for the console would be an example of a suitable solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`HTMLElement.offsetParent` is just designed to do this.

See [this document on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetParent).

Answer (score 2):

To add to Justineo's answer, if you want to do this in Chrome Devtools:

Right-click the element in the "Elements" section of the devtools and select "Store as global variable":

[image]

It should store a JavaScript variable reference to the element as "temp1":

[image]

Then just run `temp1.offsetParent` in the console to see the parent:

[image]